# Symfony Update data with a post request

Tags: php, symfony, post, symfony4, symfony-forms

I am currently trying to update a Person in a table. The Table looks the following:

[image: Table]

I want to be able to update the First-and Lastname and also the nin when I click on the Submit button.
My twig file looks like this:

```
{% block body %}
    <h1>All our Patients</h1>
    <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Firstname</th>
            <th scope="col">Lastname</th>
            <th scope="col">NIN</th>
            <th scope="col">Update</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for person in persons %}
        <tr>
            <form action="{{ path('updatePerson', {"id": person.id}) }}" method="post">
                <td>{{ person.id }}</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="firstName"  value="{{ person.firstName }}"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="lastName"  value="{{ person.lastName }}"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="nin" value="{{ person.nin }}"></td>
                <td><input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
            </form>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
{% endblock %}
```

And my controller is the following:

```
/**
     * @Route("/user/persons/{id}", name="updatePerson")
     */
    public function updatePerson(int $id): Response
    {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $person = $entityManager->getRepository(Person::class)->find($id);

        if (!$person) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException(
                'No person found for id '.$id
            );
        }

        $person->setFirstName('FirstName');
        $person->setLastName('Lastname');
        $person->setNin('00.09.69-420.2');
        $entityManager->flush();

        $persons = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Person::class)->findAll();
        return $this->render('user/person/index.html.twig', [
            'persons' => $persons,
        ]);
    }
```

Currently when I click update I just fill it what's in the "setFirstName('FirstName');". I don't really know how to pass in the correct data so it updates correctly? how would I obtain the changes I want to make by pressing submit?

Comment: just a hint:  `$person->setFirstName($request->get('FirstName'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick fix **(not recommended)**:

You should add the `name` attribute for text input tags

```
  <td><input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" value="{{ person.firstName }}"></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" value="{{ person.lastName }}"></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="nin" name="nin" value="{{ person.nin }}"></td>
```

and modify controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/user/persons/{id}", name="updatePerson")
 */
public function updatePerson(Request $request, Person $person): Response
{
    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $person->setFirstName($request->request('firstName'));
    $person->setLastName($request->request('lastName'));
    $person->setNin($request->request('nin');   

    $entityManager->flush();

    $persons = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Person::class)->findAll();

    return $this->render('user/person/index.html.twig', [
        'persons' => $persons,
    ]);
}
```

But for the best practice, you should use [Symfony Form Collection](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html) and add  [validation rules for fields](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html#constraints-in-form-classes)